# Convert Simple String Variable To HTML

Tags: html, node.js

I know this should be super simple but I can׳t get it work like i expect.
In my `Node.js` program I have a string `var` that is generated from some parameters.

```
var generatedString = "some string" + "other string";
```

I want to pass this variable to a method as `html` field so I used :

```
'<b>generatedString</b>'
```

When it print out to the browser I see: generatedString not its content. 
What is the simplest way to make it work?

Comment: Have you considered using a template? Handlebars will do this, you will have to pass it with the response! `res.send(file, {generatedString:generatedString});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same principle as in your first example.

```
'<b>' + generatedString + '</b>'
```

Or as parameter to a method

```
alert('<b>' + generatedString + '</b>');
```

Use it in a variable like this

```
var htmlString = '<b>' + generatedString + '</b>';
alert(htmlString);
```

Comment: whats get printed in the browser is generatedString just bold, not its content

Comment: No, when using the correct string concatenation it will output "some stringother string" in bold. `var generatedString = "some string" + "other string"; alert('<b>' +  generatedString + '</b>');`

Answer (score 3):

If your using a newer version of Node v4 or higher you could use **Template Literals**:

```
var name = 'Juan';
var job = 'flying penguin';

var sentence = `Hello ${name}, the ${job}!`;
console.log(sentence); // -> Hello Juan, the flying penguin!
```

Note that the pings are not (') but (`)

In your case

```
var generatedString = 'some string' + 'other string';
var yourhtml = `<b>#{generatedString}</b>`;
console.log(yourhtml); // -> <b>some string other string</b>
```

Comment: Thanks! but i get "string templates are not supported by this javascript version

Comment: You wrote node js? :)

Comment: Yes im using nodejs

Comment: What version of Nodejs? u can install n to upgrade the version :)

Comment: npm install n ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need this:
`'<b>' + generatedString + '</b>'`

Comment: whats get printed in the browser is generatedString just bold, not its content